# How to get the Respiratory Rate from the Google Fit REST API

Tags: google-fit

I am using the Google Fit REST API and want to get the respiratory rate. In the Google Fit app on Android, there is support to add Respiratory Rate. The API that I am using to fetch the data is `GET /fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/{dataSourceId}/datasets/{datasetId}` but unable to find the `dataSourceId` for respiratory rate. Unable to find anything in the documentation at https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/health. Usually, the `GET /fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources` API lists all the data sources but there is nothing for the respiratory rate. Below is the response after granting ALL the Fitness API permissions

```json
{
  "dataSource": [
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "duration", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.active_minutes"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merge_active_minutes", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_active_minutes", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "activity", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.activity.segment"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "session_activity_segment", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.apps.fitness:session_activity_segment", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "activity", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.activity.segment"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merge_activity_segments", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:merge_activity_segments", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "activity", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.activity.segment"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "session_activity_segment", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:session_activity_segment", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "body_temperature", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }, 
          {
            "optional": true, 
            "name": "body_temperature_measurement_location", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.body.temperature"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merged", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.body.temperature:com.google.android.gms:merged", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "calories", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.calories.expended"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merge_calories_expended", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:merge_calories_expended", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "distance", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.distance.delta"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merge_distance_delta", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_distance_delta", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "intensity", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.heart_minutes"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merge_heart_minutes", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "bpm", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.heart_rate.bpm"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merge_heart_rate_bpm", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "bpm", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.heart_rate.bpm"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "oxygen_saturation", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }, 
          {
            "name": "supplemental_oxygen_flow_rate", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }, 
          {
            "optional": true, 
            "name": "oxygen_therapy_administration_mode", 
            "format": "integer"
          }, 
          {
            "optional": true, 
            "name": "oxygen_saturation_system", 
            "format": "integer"
          }, 
          {
            "optional": true, 
            "name": "oxygen_saturation_measurement_method", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.oxygen_saturation"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merged", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.oxygen_saturation:com.google.android.gms:merged", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "sleep_segment_type", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.sleep.segment"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merged", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.sleep.segment:com.google.android.gms:merged", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "speed", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.speed"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merge_speed", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.speed:com.google.android.gms:merge_speed", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "steps", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.step_count.delta"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "estimated_steps", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "steps", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.step_count.delta"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "merge_step_deltas", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_step_deltas", 
      "type": "derived"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "duration", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.active_minutes"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "user_input", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input", 
      "type": "raw"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "activity", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.activity.segment"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "user_input", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input", 
      "type": "raw"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "body_temperature", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }, 
          {
            "optional": true, 
            "name": "body_temperature_measurement_location", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.body.temperature"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "user_input", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.body.temperature:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input", 
      "type": "raw"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "intensity", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.heart_minutes"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "user_input", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input", 
      "type": "raw"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "bpm", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.heart_rate.bpm"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "user_input", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input", 
      "type": "raw"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "oxygen_saturation", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }, 
          {
            "name": "supplemental_oxygen_flow_rate", 
            "format": "floatPoint"
          }, 
          {
            "optional": true, 
            "name": "oxygen_therapy_administration_mode", 
            "format": "integer"
          }, 
          {
            "optional": true, 
            "name": "oxygen_saturation_system", 
            "format": "integer"
          }, 
          {
            "optional": true, 
            "name": "oxygen_saturation_measurement_method", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.oxygen_saturation"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "user_input", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.oxygen_saturation:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input", 
      "type": "raw"
    }, 
    {
      "dataQualityStandard": [], 
      "dataType": {
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "steps", 
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ], 
        "name": "com.google.step_count.delta"
      }, 
      "dataStreamName": "user_input", 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
      }, 
      "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input", 
      "type": "raw"
    }
  ]
}
```

What data source ID do I need to use to get the respiratory rate?

Comment: I'm afraid Respiratory rate API is not documented elsewhere. Though, you may try the new API, it supports the RespiratoryRate data type 
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/connect/client/records/RespiratoryRate

Comment: Thanks @ilovesyntax This is for Kotlin but I am specifically looking for it in the REST API version.